# How to measure height and apply in view jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I want to measure the height of parent view and animate accordingly to that. I tried from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67503211/8266651). I think it returns 0.dp to me. So what is the proper way of measuring the item?

Actually I want to animate a view, but my view is 0.dp when I run the application.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MoveText() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var columnHeightDp by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val iconOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 13.dp else 0.dp, tween(1000)
    )
    val textOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 6.dp else 0.dp, tween(1000)
    )
    val viewAlpha: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) 1f else 0f, animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
        )
    )
    val heightInDp: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (visible) {
            columnHeightDp
        } else {
            0.dp
        }, animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
        )
    )
    ScrollComposeTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    with(density) {
                        columnHeightDp = coordinates.size.height.toDp()
                    }
                }
                .height(heightInDp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = iconOffsetAnimation),
                    alpha = viewAlpha,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = textOffsetAnimation),
                    text = "Hello, Anna",
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = viewAlpha),
                )
            }
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp),
                onClick = {
                    visible = !visible
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Move Text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a view with button `Move Text` and when you click that, a. view need to animate from top?

Comment: I have one `Column`. Inside that I have `Icon and Text`. When I clicked in the `Button`. I want to shrink the `Column` view, but not `Button`. I am trying to use `onGloballyPositioned` to check the children heights but it gives me 0.dp.

Comment: Will post my answer below, just copy paste and give me feedback over the comment, will try to help you.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/desertedwillingcoati you need this one then will post my answer Vivek

Comment: So what is the idiomatic way of solving this problem @GabrieleMariotti ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to achieve something like this [demo video](https://gfycat.com/desertedwillingcoati) from your question.

```
 val modifier: Modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)      
 Column(modifier = if (columnHeightDp != 0.dp) {
                modifier
                    .height(heightInDp)
            } else {
                modifier.onSizeChanged {
                    with(density) {
                        columnHeightDp = it.height.toDp()
                    }
                }.wrapContentHeight()
            },
        ) {
         // your content goes here...Image and Text
           }
```

Let me explain how i reach to this.

```
modifier = modifier.onSizeChanged {
                with(density) {
                    columnHeightDp = it.height.toDp()
                }
            }.wrapContentHeight(),
```

Here for the dynamic height calculation `onSizeChanged` method works well. So i save this in a variable as per your need. The `wrapContentHeight` method in modifier is equivalent as `WRAP_CONTENT` in xml.
It will work nicely showing both components (Image and Text)(Button). But we need the animation so what we need to do is.

```
if (columnHeightDp != 0.dp) {
                modifier
                    .height(heightInDp)
            }
```

This will apply the animation for the entire `Column` for `Image` and `Text`

Comment: what will be first condition runs?

Comment: How `onSizeChanged` works and what is the doing with `wrapContentHeight` ?

Comment: Your code works fine, but please give me the explanation..

Comment: OK will edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect example. If I don't want to show first time animation, how can I achieve this?